# PowerShell International module

Tags: powershell, module, internationalization

I'm trying to change the system locale using a PowerShell script, following instructions at
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825705.aspx#PowerShell.
However, I can't load the international module.
I can't seem to find anything by googling.
I'm using Windows 7 SP1 x64 and PowerShell 3.0.
Where can I find this module (on the local system or for download)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a part of Windows 8/Server 2012 only. see the 'Important' box at the beginning of the post